# Magento catalog image cache not creating?

Tags: magento, caching, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am working on magento 1.8 version. I have a problem with catalog images.
Some product images not showing on frontend. Actually they are coming from cache and no image is on that location.

Problem is cache is not creating properly.

```
I have done following things:-
 1. media folder permission:- 777
 2. cache clear(after clear cache it shows but after some day it happens again same)
 3. Gd library installed
 4. increased memory limit to 1024M
```

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: any help from stack overflow...?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename cache folder from media/catalog/product.

Also apply 777 permission sub directory also.

Then remove all cache and try it.